# is_front_page and is_home are not working in page.php

Tags: page-template, homepage, template-tags, frontpage

I'm trying to target my landing page with `is_front_page` or `is_home` in my `page.php` file but it's not working. I have set the `settings > reading` to a static page.

However, if I create a `page-home.php` everything works fine (without the tags of course). But, if I use the `is_front_page` or `is_home` on the index file they will work (on my blog page).

Am I just misunderstanding their function and if so, how can I target the landing page dynamically?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) : ?>
    <h1>Why not???</h1>
<?php endif; ?>

<div>
    <article>
        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' ); ?>
    </article>

    <aside>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </aside>
</div>

<?php comments_template(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you take a look at implementation of `is_front_page`, you will see the following:

```
/**
 * Is the query for the front page of the site?
 *
 * This is for what is displayed at your site's main URL.
 *
 * Depends on the site's "Front page displays" Reading Settings 'show_on_front' and 'page_on_front'.
 *
 * If you set a static page for the front page of your site, this function will return
 * true when viewing that page.
 *
 * Otherwise the same as @see WP_Query::is_home()
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 * @uses is_home()
 * @uses get_option()
 *
 * @return bool True, if front of site.
 */
function is_front_page() {
    // most likely case
    if ( 'posts' == get_option( 'show_on_front') && $this->is_home() )
        return true;
    elseif ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front') && get_option( 'page_on_front' ) && $this->is_page( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

So I think the answer of your question is in this sentence `If you set a static page for the front page of your site, this function will return true when viewing that page.` It means that to make your page.php working as you want, you need to go to the "Settings" -> "Reading" page and set "Front page displays" option.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I have the reading settings set to static page (just clarified that above). But the problem still exists.

Comment: Is the above snippet from the wp core? I don't assume that I have to implement it, or?

Comment: Yes it is from the WP core, it is WP_Query class.

Comment: Add `var_dump(get_option( 'show_on_front'));` and `var_dump(get_option( 'page_on_front' ));` to see what they return.

Comment: Where exactly should I add them?

Comment: At your `page.php` template and post here what they return

Comment: OK, they echo out as: string(4) "page" string(1) "6"

Comment: Then check if row with ID equals to "6" in the wp_posts table have post_type column equals to "page"

Comment: Open this url in your browser: http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=6&action=edit and if you see that the page section selected in admin menu, then it means that it is the page, if post section selected then it is post.

Comment: Yes it does. What's strange though is that the post title is "About" and NOT "Home"!?

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks so much Eugene! I had the wrong page selected in settings > reading ... doh!